# PHP: ideal string method

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP and I was wondering which is the ideal method to turn the text in the else statement below into code. 
I think my old way to escape every **quote** with a **\"** seems not to be the best way so 
how would you do it?

```
<?php
if (strlen($finalArray['Lat']) <= 0){

} 
else 
{
<a name="openframe"></a>
Loc: <br/>
<a href="#xmap" onclick="spoiliut('pmap');" title="<?php echo $finalArray['Name']; ?>" target="_self"><strong> <?php echo $finalArray['Name']; ?> </strong>
</a>
?>
```

Thanks for tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP can be mixed with HTML. You could do this:

```
<?php if (strlen($finalArray['Lat']) <= 0) : ?>
    <p>some html</p>
<?php else : ?>
    <a name="openframe"></a>
    Loc: <br/>
    <a href="#xmap" onclick="spoiliut('pmap');" title="<?= $finalArray['Name'] ?>" target="_self"><strong> <?= $finalArray['Name'] ?> </strong>
    </a>
<?php endif ; ?>
```

Comment: Wow this will speed up my workflow! Thank you all for the great examples.

Comment: @Michael, You could show your appreciation with an up vote. ;) BTW, I've edited my answer to show the PHP echo short tag. That will speed things up too!

Answer (score 3):

Two options, the first looks like: (It works because if statements carry between php tags)

```
<?php
if (strlen($finalArray['Lat']) <= 0)
{

} 
else 
{
?>

<a name="openframe"></a>
Loc: <br/>
<a href="#xmap" onclick="spoiliut('pmap');" title="<?php echo $finalArray['Name']; ?>" target="_self"><strong> <?php echo $finalArray['Name']; ?> </strong>
</a>

<?php
}
?>
```

And the second is the Heredoc syntax
It looks like:

```
<?php
if (strlen($finalArray['Lat']) <= 0)
{

} 
else 
{
    echo <<<EOF
    <a name="openframe"></a>
    Loc: <br/>
    <a href="#xmap" onclick="spoiliut('pmap');" title="{$finalArray['Name']}" target="_self"><strong> {$finalArray['Name']} </strong>
    </a>
EOF;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if (strlen($finalArray['Lat']) <= 0){

} 
else 
{
?>
<a name="openframe"></a>
Loc: <br/>
<a href="#xmap" onclick="spoiliut('pmap');" title="<?php echo $finalArray['Name']; ?>" target="_self"><strong> <?php echo $finalArray['Name']; ?> </strong>
</a>
```